# How to enable tomcat servlet metrics in Spring Boot 2.1.3

Tags: prometheus, grafana, spring-micrometer, embedded-tomcat

I'm trying to monitor actuator metrics in Spring Boot 2.1.3 with embedded tomcat, but the metrics do not include the tomcat.servlet.* and tomcat.cache.* metrics.

Currently available metrics are below

{"names":["logback.events","tomcat.sessions.expired","jvm.memory.committed","jvm.buffer.memory.used","jvm.memory.max","jvm.threads.live","jvm.threads.peak","jvm.threads.states","jvm.memory.used","process.uptime","tomcat.global.sent","tomcat.sessions.rejected","process.cpu.usage","tomcat.global.request.max","jdbc.connections.active","tomcat.global.request","jvm.classes.loaded","jvm.classes.unloaded","tomcat.sessions.active.current","hikaricp.connections.idle","tomcat.global.received","tomcat.sessions.alive.max","jvm.gc.live.data.size","jdbc.connections.max","jdbc.connections.min","hikaricp.connections.pending","method.timed","http.server.requests","hikaricp.connections","process.files.open","hikaricp.connections.active","hikaricp.connections.creation","tomcat.threads.config.max","tomcat.sessions.active.max","tomcat.global.error","process.start.time","jvm.buffer.count","hikaricp.connections.max","hikaricp.connections.min","tomcat.threads.current","jvm.buffer.total.capacity","process.files.max","jvm.gc.memory.promoted","hikaricp.connections.usage","system.load.average.1m","jvm.gc.max.data.size","gauge.UserController.getUser.executionTime.seconds","hikaricp.connections.timeout","tomcat.threads.busy","system.cpu.count","hikaricp.connections.acquire","jvm.gc.pause","tomcat.sessions.created","jvm.threads.daemon","system.cpu.usage","jvm.gc.memory.allocated"]}

Is there any property that needs to be set in spring so that all the tomcat metrics are exposed. I've already tried managemet.metrics.enable.tomcat=true But it did not work.

Dependencies are:

```
 <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a bug within the micrometer API. Version: micrometer-core-1.1.3

Bug report from Github:  https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/1754